# Gulp error in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, babeljs

I am using laravel 5.3,
There is something wrong when running `gulp`,as follow:

```
D:\wnmp\www\laravel-5-3-demo>gulp
(node:12992) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[02:47:21] Using gulpfile D:\wnmp\www\laravel-5-3-demo\gulpfile.js
[02:47:21] Starting 'all'...
[02:47:21] Starting 'sass'...
[02:47:21] Finished 'sass' after 375 ms
[02:47:21] Starting 'webpack'...
{ [Error: ./~/babel-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/Example.vue
Module build failed: Error: Cannot remove "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs" from the plugin list.
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\wnmp\www\laravel-5-3-demo\node_modules\babel-preset-es2015-webpack\index.js:35:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at D:\wnmp\www\laravel-5-3-demo\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:324:15
    at Array.map (native)
 @ ./resources/assets/js/components/Example.vue 2:17-130
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js]
  message: './~/babel-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/Example.vue\nModule build failed: Error: Cannot remove "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs" from the plugin list.\n    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\\wnmp\\www\\laravel-5-3-demo\\node_modules\\babel-preset-es2015-webpack\\index.js:35:11)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)\n    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)\n    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)\n    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)\n    at D:\\wnmp\\www\\laravel-5-3-demo\\node_modules\\babel-core\\lib\\transformation\\file\\options\\option-manager.js:324:15\n    at Array.map (native)\n @ ./resources/assets/js/components/Example.vue 2:17-130\n @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'webpack-stream',
  __safety: { toString: [Function: bound ] } }
```

According to this thread, https://github.com/gajus/babel-preset-es2015-webpack/issues/14
There are 2 solutions:
1.

```
npm i -D -E babel-preset-es2015@6.9.0
```

2.

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}]
  ]
}
```

I want to use the 2nd method, but I have 2 questions:

1.Where should I put `.babelrc` file?
2.Do I need to remove anything, and then reinstall it ?

Comment: Same problem on macOS El Capitan. Have you found any solution yet? Both ways seems not to work.

Comment: @Deazl ,download `laravel-elixir-vue` master from github, then unzip,rename it to `laravel-elixir-vue` ,and put it into `node_modules` folder,then,change `"laravel-elixir-vue": "^0.1.4"` to `"laravel-elixir-vue": "file:./node_modules/laravel-elixir-vue"`in `package.json`.

Comment: Wow, finally it works. Thank you soo much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try trashing your node_modules folder and then nom install again to see if that fixes the missing modules.

Sometimes, everything doesn't get installed. Pay attention to the output messages incase something is preventing acorn from installing.